# Complicated mysql query across two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**Table 1**: invTypes with columns `typeID`,`groupID`,`typeName`,`description`
**Table 2**: item_value with columns `typeID`,`volume`,`avg`,`max`,`min`,`stddev`,`percentile`,`updated_on`

I need to return all of the above columns where the latest `updated_on` (datetime) field as the deciding factor.  I would like to return the latest datetime for each day with all of the information from table 1 and table 2 as the result.

Comment: It is not clear what relationship there is between the two tables. How do we know which rows from invTypes to select?

Comment: Table 1 consists of a list of items.  Table two consists of a list of values for those items.  The values are updated every 30 minutes.  While table 1 will only have 1 of each typeID, table 2 will have many.  I am not sure if i have answered your question or not but hopefully you can understand better.  I have to apologize, my knowledge of databases is limited and I usually dread heading this direction.

Comment: You neglected to include `typeID` in the list of columns for the `item_value` table -- thanks for the update.

Comment: I apologize, it should have been there.  Too many hours trying to figure this out.  The good thing is that my query is close to what you posted below but looks like it went through a blender lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get the rows corresponding to the most recent `updated_on` for each date in your `item_value` table:

```
SELECT
  invTypes.*,
  item_value.*
FROM
  item_value
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      MAX(updated_on) AS `updated_on`
    FROM
      item_value
    GROUP BY
      DATE(updated_on)
  ) latest
ON
  latest.updated_on = item_value.updated_on
INNER JOIN
  invTypes
ON
  invTypes.typeID = item_value.typeID
ORDER BY
  item_value.updated_on
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I wish I had half the knowledge of databases as you do.  There is a minor error caused from shooting this from the hip on the 10th line.  Instead of inv_value it should be item_value.  Im only mentioning this so that if other read they will not get confused.  Again thank you very much.

Comment: In addition I have updated the question for accuracy.  Thank you again.

Comment: Is there any way I could talk you into explaing how this works?

Comment: Additionally, I dont understand how this selects the last entry from each day.

Comment: Actually as I have ran this a few times now, I get different results each time.  The results seem to be random as I have only seen a couple times where the same item result has been returned.

Comment: Then your data is changing, or there are multiple rows sharing the same max `updated_on` value on the same dates, as this query is completely deterministic. I don't think you described the data you want correctly in your question, as I don't see why you would want to run the query you asked for. I wrote that as a comment 45 minutes ago but deleted it since I wasn't sure how to put that to you...

Comment: Perhaps If i said the reason I am looking for the data you could think of a better question for me to ask.  I did have some trouble asking the question.

Comment: I have a very large table of over 19,000 items.  Of which a few exists that I want to know the market values of and how log how they change through out the day.    Table two contains a constantly updated list of values for each of the items.  The reason that I just want the highest date is just to pick a number from each day that would stand out.  Perhaps I should choose the highest avg value for the day.  I then take and graph by day as to give us a 30 day display of the items.

Comment: Is this graph going to have a separate line for each product? Or are you going to have as many graphs as there are items or what? What your original question asks is for the most recent market price (in the whole table) on each date, where it sounds like what you really wanted is the most recent price *for each item* on each date... grouping by two things (typeID, date) rather than one thing as you asked (date). Am I on the right track?

Comment: The item database contains all Items that are in the game EvE Online.  Of those items there are a small set of about 15 that my corp wants to track.  There will be a separate graph for each item that will have the typeID,volume,avg,max,min,stddev,percentile,updated_on needed.  The reason that I was asking for the most recent item is because I was going to track the last entry for the day although this will introduce a very large probability for error because of the way people play the game.

Comment: Perhaps The best way would be to track the highest high for the day, the most recent avg for the day and the lowest low for the day.  But once again, I am at a complete loss as to how to get this data in one nice query.  With my knowledge I would have to pull this with many queries that would be fed to php to form other queries which would eat a ton of resources.

Comment: To get values for a specific item, just add a `WHERE` clause to both the inner and outer queries, like `WHERE invTypes.TypeID = 5`. To get the lowest, highest, or average balance use the `MIN`, `MAX` and `AVG` functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Thank you again dan.  I will reread the documentation at mysql.com.  I find that there documentation is a little difficult to understand because most of the examples are very involved or involve more than necessary to demonstrate what it is that is being discussed.  I think all in all I am just real weak when it comes to queries so once again I want to thank you for all of your time and assistance.  If I could thumbs up ya again I would.

Comment: Additionally, the min max and avg values are pulled from another site.  I simply log them every 30 minutes for my own use.  This is why I would be interested in a query that would give me the highest high, latest avg and lowest low of each day.  The information would not be perfectly accurate but would show us all we needed to see about the data.

Comment: I see. The highest high will be the `MAX(\`max\`)`, the lowest low `MIN(\`min\`)`, and the latest average would be the plain `avg` corresponding to the row with `MAX(updated_on)`, which you get with a subquery like the one in my answer. Like anything else, writing complicated SQL queries is something you learn over time with practice. You have to think about the relational algebra going on at a lower level, which you learn by writing queries and seeing the results, then everything clicks and it becomes straightforward to write whatever you need.

Comment: Well with as much discussion that we had on this, I will be able to put quite a bit more together now.  I still have questions, but this is neither the time nor place for it as I dont want to drift too far from the OP.  Additionally, I dont even know how to ask some of the questions just yet.  Heck, it took me longer to ask my original question than it did for you to answer it.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table1.uniqueid = table2.uniqueid ON table2 
ORDER BY update_on DESC 
GROUP BY (DATE(updated_on))
```

Comment: This will not return the data for the latest updated_on row within each date. It's also not a valid `SELECT` query; your clauses are out of order. The query for that involves at least one join to a subquery. This answer is definitely incorrect, even though we don't have all the necessary information to produce the correct answer yet.

Comment: I am not too great with joins, just trying to help